# How to break 信じようとしていただけかも知れない into separate parts?

Tags: meaning, words, parsing

I tried, but I came up with either:

1. 信じる(~よう(vol.)) + とする(~ていた(prog. past)) + だけ + かもしれない。
2. 信じよう + として + いただける(stem) + かもしれない。

I highly doubt that second one is true, because かもしれない "takes" dictionary or past forms, but I am nit sure what だけ would mean in this sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 信じようとしていただけかも知れない

#### Pulling it apart

Let's break this down.

> 信じようとしていた

In turn, this phrase is:

- 信じよう
  The volitional of 信じる.
- と
  The particle.
- して
  する in the conjunctive ～て form.
- いた
  いる in the past tense / completed aspect.

The main meaning here is "had been trying to believe".  The construction `[VERB: volitional]`とする parses out to "try to `[VERB]`".

> だけ

"Only" or "just".

> かも知れない

In turn, this is:

- か
  Question particle, also used in certain kinds of coordinating clauses.
- も
  Inclusive particle: "even, also"
- 知【し】れない
  知【し】る in the potential negative form.

The main meaning of the construction ～かもしれない is "I can't know [for sure] if ～", used idiomatically to mean "it might be ～".

#### Putting it back together

Literally then, we have:

> 信じようとしていただけかも知れない
>     believe `[VOL]` was doing only might be
>   → was trying to believe only might be

Putting that into sensible English:

> It might only be that [someone] was trying to believe

Comment: Very specific explanation. Thank you very much. I understood most of this sentence out of hand. Just とする and だけ threw me off. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

It's the first one. Simply put, the second one doesn't make any sense. I can't come up with any kind of reasonable explanation for why something would be written that way, nor have I ever seen the stem of `いただける` used as a noun.

Frankly only after reading this question did I even realize that there were dictionary entries for `いただける` specifically, since it comes from the potential form of `いただく`.

The first one, on the other hand, pretty clearly means something like

> Maybe (I) was just trying to believe it

Though the topic is omitted and could consequently could be anyone, obviously including people other than the speaker. I just default to `I`.